# How to make code compatible with different library version to be able to run on different environments?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am working on a SQL-tool to extract and display data from the Hadoop ecosystem. I have used Spark and Hive libraries to achieve SQL connectivity and browsing.

I am using some APIs, classes, that I have extended from Spark and Hive and its internal methods that I have used. Now many of the APIs and Class constructors and method syntax have changed.

I need to some way to handle multiple version of Spark and Hive libraries in my code so that I can support wide variety to versions of Spark and Hive and its combinations.

In my tool, I had to extend many classes of Spark SQL and write my own implementations. To support multiple version of Spark I have currently used reflection to achieve Spark method/APIs call compatibility.

Example:
Say ThriftBinaryCLIServive is a class that I have extended.
The constructor has changed in Hive1.2 and Hive2.1.
In Hive1.2, ThriftBinaryCLIServive(CLIService cliService)
In Hive2.1, ThriftBinaryCLIServive(CLIService cliService, Runnable oomHook)

To solve this
I have written a separate version of extended classes say:
CustomThriftBinaryCLIServive1_2(compatible with Hive 1.2) and CustomThriftBinaryCLIServive2_1(compatible with Hive 2.1) and keep them different source folders.
I use Maven to compile packages in specific source folders at a time.
I use reflection to instantiate appropriate class on runtime depending on Hive version And use the ThriftBinaryCLIServive as the reference class.

Currently, this approach works for me. But I see code maintainability problems in future and code duplication to some extent and I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

I have also tried a Custom Class Loader approach where I used two different class loaders to load class of different versions but did not help much, also that is not so manageable in long run and hard to debug as well.

Can someone suggest other better ways by which I can solve this problem?

Comment: do you have a requirement to support multiple versions of Spark/Hive within single version or your library? I would release separate versions with separate Spark/Hive versions support to remove complexity

Comment: not necessarily, But I would like to avoid creating multiple jars as for multiple versions, as even in minor version changes of Spark or Hive various method syntaxes have changed.

Comment: got it, breaking changes (e.g. syntax) in minor version updates is bad practice btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use adapter `design pattern` for this purpose. Whenever a new version is introduced with different API, you will need to just introduce a new `Adapter` which will direct call from existing code to new API.

Answer (score 0):

Program to the lowest common denominator. If version 1 provides feature A and version 2 provides features A and B, in your code you may use feature A but not feature B.

Where that is not possible,  split your own code into a part that depends on the version of the library, and a part that does not. If necessary,  have the version dependent library implement a Facade that translates the varying API of the library into a common internal API that your other code uses.

Use a modern  version control system that enables easy branching development. Accept that you will have to simultaneously work on different versions of your code simultaneously,  merging between branches (for different versions). Merging from old versions to new versions usually works better.

Accept that you can not support old versions forever. Just as old versions of the library become obsolete and no longer supported,  so must old versions of your code.